# Ajax request caching: "weird" behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, caching, xmlhttprequest

I have a javascript application which requests objects via a RESTful API. In many cases, I need to get the same object in different parts of the application; instead of caching them manually (inside an object, for example), I want to leverage the browser cache.

So, I made the server set a `Cache-control: public, max-age=30` header, but apparently the responses are not always taken from cache.

Weird enough, it seems like requests made via jQuery are cached **only** if both conditions apply:

- run inside a `window` `"load"` event handler
- wrapped in `setTimeout(..., 0)`

When using plain `XMLHttpRequest`, apparently it's enough that *at least one* of the aforementioned conditions is met, for the cached version to be used..

Here is the full example code, along with HTTP responses, etc: https://gist.github.com/rshk/82ff17d16d363b6b71cf

Anyone has an explanation for this?

(I'm perfectly fine with wrapping code execution in `window` load handler, and in fact it already is, but having to wrap requests in `setTimeout(..., 0)` is just plain weird..).

Comment: It sounds like an encapsulation (scoping) issue.  Can you give us some example code?

Comment: @Archer all the code is here: https://gist.github.com/rshk/82ff17d16d363b6b71cf but I don't see where there might be scoping issues..

Comment: I admit it sounds strange, but the fact that putting it in an enclosed function fixes the issue does suggest it.  Have you tried `(function() { // your code })();` ?

Comment: Yeah, I tried, with no difference from the "unwrapped" code

Comment: Apparently is not the enclosed function, but running "asynchronously".. a part when using plain XHR instead, which works almost the expected way (although request is still done twice)

Comment: I think maybe manual caching may be the best thing.  You may "fix" this issue and then find later that it's failing under different circumstances.  Sounds too iffy to me to rely on.  It also sounds strange as I've never had issues like this before.  One question - do you have the developer console open at the time?

Comment: The problem with manual caching is you basically have to roll your own cache management, including expires, garbage collection (it's a single-page app, I cannot risk filling the user RAM by caching too many objects, ...) all stuff that's already implemented in the browser and which I'd like to use.. Yes, I have the developer console, and I see the 8 requests (the fact that the browser is using the cache is well abstracted away from the user, which is good IMHO).

Comment: That's obviously another conversation.  But the reason I asked about the developer console is that by default requests are not cached if you have it open (at least in Chrome).

Comment: @Archer ah ok, no, in Firefox apparently doesn't change that (I tried both *with* and *without* console)

Comment: I don't know what to suggest, but I do know that it must be something else causing this issue, as it's not normal behaviour.  Copy/paste this into the console window of this page and you'll see the same ID over and over again... `$.ajax({ cache: true, url: "http://httpbin.org/cache/30" }).done(function(data){ console.log(data.headers['X-Request-Id']); });`